# Python program decision control issue

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to create a code library where I can store code snippets I find over time and retrieve them. Here is my code so far.

```
# Python Code Library User Interface

import sys

class CodeLib:
    codes = []
    option = ['help (-h)', 'list (-l)', 'import (-i)', 'quit (-q)']

#What does the user want to do?
    print "Welcome to the Code Library"
    print "What would you like to do? \n %s" % option
    choice = raw_input()
    print choice
    if choice == 'quit' or '-q':
        sys.exit()
    length = len(choice)
# Getting name of file to import if user chooses import before
# viewing the code list
    if choice[0] == 'i':
        _file_ = choice[6:length]
    elif choice[:2] == '-i':
        _file_ = choice[2:length]
# imports file if user chose import before viewing code list
    if choice[0:5] == 'import' or choice [0:2] == '-i':
        import _file_
# If user chose option other than import at beginning
# then perform option chosen then give ability to do something else
    while choice != 'quit' or '-q':
# provides basic help menu
        if choice == 'help' or '-h':
            print
            print '''(list or -l) brings up a list of code snippet names
(import or -i)/file_name brings up the code snippet you chose \n'''
# provides list of code files
        elif choice == 'list' or '-l':
            print codes
            print option[2], "file name"
            _file2_ = raw_input()
            import _file2_
# imports code file
        else:
            _file2_ = raw_input()
            import _file2_
# Next user option                  
        print "What would you like to do?"
        choice = raw_input
```

Now I know this is very incomplete so far. But the issue I am running into is that no matter what I enter as choice. The program does the first if statement, which exits the program. I have commented out the first if statement and tried again. But then no matter what I enter as choice. It performs this first if statement in the while loop and I just get stuck in a loop. So I'm not sure what is wrong but can someone help me out here?

Comment: This gets asked so very many times. I wonder if it'd be asked less if "if" and "or" were easier to search for.

Comment: Also [if x or y or z == blah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah) and about 100 other questions.

Comment: Why do so many people coming from C++ or Java expect this to work? If you write `while (choice != "quit" || "-q")` in C++, it fails for exactly the same reason `while choice != "quit" or "-q"` does in Python…

Comment: It doesn't exactly "fail". It just doesn't do what OP expects it to do.

Comment: @abarnert Because we say things like "if she's short or fat, I'm not interested."

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question. However I may not have been clear enough when. I am basically relearning to program altogether because it has been a long time since I have done anything in c or java

Comment: @2rs2ts That is the exact reason why I thought it should have worked the way I wrote it. But, as I said. I'm basically relearning everything. With just basic recollection of syntax and method names and a general idea of what they do

Comment: While everyone else has pointed out the way that the boolean operator works, I should also note that your last line should be `choice = raw_input()`. You have to call `raw_input` or else you won't actually prompt for input. The difference here is that you must use the parentheses (`()`) to call or invoke that function. You don't have them, so, without getting too technical, you're assigning the function itself to `choice`. If your code is working now, then you didn't paste it correctly and you do have those parentheses there.

Comment: Oh now i see what you are saying. My apologies on that. I must have left that out when pasting my code. the parentheses are there in my code. Sorry about the confusion and thanks for your input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "or '-q'" part checks if the string '-q' is not false, which is true for any nonempty string. Change this line to:

```
if choice == 'quit' or choice == '-q':
```

Comment: OP should also check out the argparse module for this kind of thing, it eliminates a lot of needles if-thenning  http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: I am going to look into that argparse module in a bit. Thank you forb the link! I realize all the if statments are a really...elementary way of doing things and I am trying to become more efficient

Answer (score 3):

The condition `choice == 'quit' or '-q'` (and similar) always returns True, because `'-q'` evaulates to True and (True or Something) is always True.

You most probably wanted something like

```
choice == 'quit' or choice == '-q'
```

or

```
choice in ['quit', '-q']
```

Comment: Ah, now that makes a lit of sense. Thanks for the help! I am going to mess with it some more now and see where it gets me.

Comment: Okay so now everything is working correctly! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are creating an object in a way that I don't believe to be standard. Typically, you define methods for a class with `def func(self,arg):` blocks inside the `class foo:` block. The initializer method is indicated by the name `__init__(self,args)`. Note that there are two '_' characters before and after init.

If you just want to run some code in a simple python script, you don't need it to be inside any block. You can just do something like:

```
print "Welcome to the Code Library"
print "What would you like to do? \n %s" % option
choice = raw_input()
print choice
if choice == 'quit' or '-q':
    sys.exit()
length = len(choice)
#More code goes here
```

Comment: This isn't really "non-standard". It is uncommon, and silly, and almost certainly not what the OP actually wants to do… but it work, and there are non-silly use cases for putting code (other than method definitions and class attribute assignments) directly in a class definition…

Comment: Also, this isn't related to the OP's question or the problem he's trying to solve.

Comment: Okay. thanks for the info on that. Ill get rid of the class for now until I understand more about methods and functions